# OCaml - converting a Set to a string

Tags: string, functional-programming, set, ocaml

I have been making use of Sets in an OCaml program.

However I need to add capability to convert a set of strings to a single string.

For Example: a Set `"a", "b", "c"` would convert to String `"{a b c}"`.

I have had a look at the Set.iter function but can't figure out how to do this?

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your set contains strings, you could use this:

```
module MySet = Set.Make(String)

let string_of_set set =
    "{" ^ (String.concat " " (MySet.elements set)) ^ "}"
```

Comment: I think using  (MySet.fold (^) set "{") ^ "}" would be a bit more efficient

Comment: That looks likely quadratic to me. Try timing them.